# Why do I have to specify an HTTP status code when providing a response model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

What is the difference between  `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)` and
 `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, object)` in ASP.NET Web API?

If the model corresponding to object does not have a status, is it not going to set the HttpStatusCode to true or false?

I have come to this question because of the following scenario

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, ModelObject object)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && id == object.objectID)
            {
                db.Entry(object).State = EntityState.Modified;

                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

**if i check httpresponsemessage.statuscode it shows httpresponsemessage is null in the calling method even if the line executes

Task response = httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, modelObject);

```
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).Result;
```

is this is correct

Comment: maybe you need   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,ex.Message);
                }

Comment: I have ammended my question with the invoke part of PUT method. Can you please have a look. I may be doing something wrong over there in the return type and serialization

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

create only a response with httpStatusCode

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"this test message")
```

create a response with httpStatusCode associated with HTTPResponseMessage

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage PutApplicationRole(){return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);} if i tried  to get this value (message.IsSuccessStatusCode) in my controller what will it return. Here i am getting null eventhough i set the HttpStatusCode

Comment: I have come to thid question because if i use the code mentioned in my comment it is giving a null response. and i f i use Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, modelobject) i am not getting null reference

Answer (score 0):

According to your phrasing, you seem to be confusing metadata and payload.

The status line and headers of an HTTP message describe what's going on on the HTTP level, so a client application ("user agent") knows how to interpret the response.

Then there's the payload, that which the server wishes to return to the client. While the headers *describe* the payload, the payload has no influence whatsoever on the HTTP side of things.

The following repsonse is entirely valid:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
...

{
    "found" : "true"
}
```

And so is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

{
    "status" : "error"
}
```

WebAPI is not going to look at your payload to determine the status code (because there is no relation between the two whatsoever), so you can specify the response code and its payload separately.